# on load event not fired for window.open

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, window, onload

I am trying to display a loading icon before downloading the respective PDF files by using window.open function however I am having difficulties waiting for the window.open to complete before dismissing the loading icon

```
let window_open = window.open("api/dummyGenerateAdhocTicketPDF?download="+download+"&client_id="+client_id+"&user_id="+user_id+"&manual_ticket_id_array="+manual_ticket_id);
window_open.addEventListener('load', function(){console.log("TESTING")}, false);
```

The load event handler was never triggered, and hence the console log testing was never fired but the PDF has been successfully downloaded.

**---EDIT---**

I tried changing the URL being opened with window.open to `www.google.com` to which the load event works, hence I suspect the issue to be with how laravel is passing the download response in the controller as shown below

```
return response()->download($tmpFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The load event will not be executed when using window.open to open a new window, because the load event only applies to the main window.

Here's the updated code. Try this:

```
    let window_open = window.open("api/dummyGenerateAdhocTicketPDF?...URL");
    window_open.onload = function() {
      console.log("Hello");
    };
```

Comment: i have tried this but to no avail. I think it's something to do with the download response from laravel

Comment: Can you surround that with a try-catch block? Maybe something with the backend code